# Не работает очередь в Redis

Tags: python, redis

есть 2 файла - мойщик и сушильщик.
однако при вызове в командной строке

```
py redis_washer.py &
```

Сначала полностью выполняется первая программа, и только потом я могу вызвать вторую

а нужно,чтобы они работали вместе
мойщик помыл одну тарелку, сушильщик ее сразу высушил.

у меня получается так

```
C:\Users\User>py redis_washer.py &
Washer is starting
Washed salad
Washed bread
Washed soup
Washed oil chicken
Washer is done

C:\Users\User>py redis_dryer.py
Dryer is working
Dried salad
Dried bread
Dried soup
Dried oil chicken
dishes are dried
```

проблему так и не нашел

Comment: А чего вы ждали, когда выполняли **последовательно** две разные программы? Они не будут выполнятся одновременно.

Comment: Вы можете написать банально написать по очереди "помыл, высушил", а можете сделать это с помощью синхронизированных потоков

Comment: @Стас собственно выбрал 2 вариант. код сверил с примером - вроде все тоже самое. Тогда вопрос-как можно запустить их одновременно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема никак не связана с `redis` или `python`. Тут дело в том, как вы запускаете программу. Вы используете `unix` способ запуска программы в фоне. В Windows `cmd` `&` не работает и чтобы запустить программу в фоне нужно делать так:

```
START /B py redis_washer.py
```

Только учтите, что если программа выводит в консоль, то этот текст будет смешан с приглашением, вашим вводом и выводом программ, которые вы запускаете далее.

Т.е. когда после запуска получаем в консоли `C:\Users\User>Washer is starting`, то это потому, что:

1. `cmd` запустил `py redis_washer.py` в фоновом режиме
2. после этого `cmd` напечатал приглашение ввода новой команды `C:\Users\User>`
3. после этого (точнее это происходит параллельно, но по скорости не yспевает), программа делает свое первый вывод в консоль. И он выводится после приглашениея.

Если в этот момент ввести новую команду и нажать `ENTER`, то она выполнится, параллельно с уже запущенной. А вывод этих двух программ будет перемешан в консоли.

Попробуйте создать в том же каталоге файл `demo.bat` с содержимым:

```
START /B py redis_washer.py
START /B py redis_dryer.py
```

И потом запустить его из командной строки:

```
demo.bat
```

Это запустит обе команды параллельно.

Comment: получается тоже самое, только поменялось  'C:\Users\User>Washer is starting'

Comment: Нет, это не тоже самое. Ведь приглашение показалось и вы можете вводить следующую команду.  Дополнил ответ.

Comment: откройте 313 страницу тут - https://ru.pdfdrive.com/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-python-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-e186869656.html.  Так проще объяснить,мою проблему

Comment: У проблемы сформулированной в описании причина именно такая, как написано в ответе. Если есть еще какая-то проблема, то нужно ее описать, лучше, в отдельном вопросе.

Comment: Если ответ в чем то неясен, я с радостью его улучшу. Мне бы только знать, что непонятно.

Comment: Прочитал дополненный ответ,выполнил, все сработало. спасибо!  только кто мг подумать,что будет все так запутанно)